# getElementByName vs getElementbyID or Two Values for Same Element in Same Select Option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a shopping cart form that NEEDS the value="id" for the Shopping Cart Script to show the Product Name of what the user chose. The result of this in the cart is "FirstProduct" etc.

I wrote a script to calculate a price based upon what the user chooses from the combination of three dropdowns then calculates the price based upon a number "8.0" etc.

I am unable to get both scripts working *(the shopping cart script is offsite and not editable)* so I need to get my price script to use document.getElementsByName()  but it does not work.

If I change the numbers from a name= to value= and use document.getElementById() then the price script works fine, but then the shopping cart just shows the Number that is used to calculate cost, not the "FirstProduct" name that is needed.

If this is not possible to work this way... OR would it be possible to have two Values in an option, like: option value[1]="8.0" value[2]="FirstProduct" or something similar?

```
    <html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<form id="shopping_cart" onsubmit="" action="" method="" target=""> 
    <select id="chooseproduct" onchange="getprice()">
        <option name="2.0" value="FirstProduct">FirstProduct</option>
        <option name="2.5" value="SecondProduct">SecondProduct</option>
        <option name="3.5" value="ThirdProduct">ThirdProduct</option>
        <option name="4.0" value="FourthProduct">FourthProduct</option>
    </select>

    <select id="choosecolor" onchange="getprice()">
        <option name="3.2" value="FirstColor">FirstColor</option>
        <option name="4.6" value="SecondColor">SecondColor</option>
        <option name="5.8" value="ThirdColor">ThirdColor</option>
        <option name="7.3" value="FourthColor">FourthColor</option>
    </select>   

    <select id="choosesize" onchange="getprice()">
        <option name="8.0"  value="FirstSize">FirstSize</option>
        <option name="9.0"  value="SecondSize">SecondSize</option>
        <option name="12.5" value="ThirdSize">ThirdSize</option>
        <option name="16.0" value="FourthSize">FourthSize</option>
    </select>       


    <div>Result is:</div><div id="result"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getprice()
        {
                var product = document.getElementsByName("chooseproduct").name;
                var color = document.getElementsByName("choosecolor").name;
                var size = document.getElementsByName("choosesize").name;
                var calculate = product*color*size;
                var result = document.getElementsByName("result");
                    result.innerHTML = calculate;

        }
        </script>
</form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A quick point, you want getElementById(..) not getElementsByName(..), the latter of which returns a collection of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom data attribute for the price, rather than the name or something else, as it makes more semantic sense. 
See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for a description of using data attributes.

Something like:

```
<form id="shopping_cart" onsubmit="" action="" method="" target=""> 
    <select id="chooseproduct" onchange="getprice()">
        <option data-price="2.0" value="FirstProduct">FirstProduct</option>
        <option data-price="2.5" value="SecondProduct">SecondProduct</option>
        <option data-price="3.5" value="ThirdProduct">ThirdProduct</option>
        <option data-price="4.0" value="FourthProduct">FourthProduct</option>
    </select>

    <select id="choosecolor" onchange="getprice()">
        <option data-price="3.2" value="FirstColor">FirstColor</option>
        <option data-price="4.6" value="SecondColor">SecondColor</option>
        <option data-price="5.8" value="ThirdColor">ThirdColor</option>
        <option data-price="7.3" value="FourthColor">FourthColor</option>
    </select>   

    <select id="choosesize" onchange="getprice()">
        <option data-price="8.0"  value="FirstSize">FirstSize</option>
        <option data-price="9.0"  value="SecondSize">SecondSize</option>
        <option data-price="12.5" value="ThirdSize">ThirdSize</option>
        <option data-price="16.0" value="FourthSize">FourthSize</option>
    </select>       


    <div>Result is:</div><div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getprice()
{
    var calculate = 0;

    var productEle = document.getElementById("chooseproduct");
    var colorEle = document.getElementById("choosecolor");
    var sizeEle = document.getElementById("choosesize");
    if (productEle.selectedIndex == -1 || colorEle.selectedIndex == -1 || sizeEle.selectedIndex == -1) {
        // Do something when they're not all selected
    } else {
        var product = productEle.options[productEle.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price")
        var color = colorEle.options[colorEle.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price")
        var size = sizeEle.options[sizeEle.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price")
        calculate = product*color*size;
    }    
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML = calculate;

}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: I like the looks of this, let me review the details and see if I can figure out how it works.  Thanks.

Comment: This does seem like the best option for my post.  When writing this post I shortened my code for the question.  When incorporating this into my full code, I realized that I the third component 'choosesize' is not from a select option, but instead displayed from a precalculated size from another script, and to get that value it would be: var size = document.getElementById("choosesize").value;  So, I am confused by the if else formula and how to have one set value and still use the first two, "chooseproduct" and "choosecolor"?

Answer (score 0):

You can store in a same attribut both values. I recommand JSON to do that.

Use [JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to read JSON object and [JSON.stringify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to store JSON object.

**Example** :

*STORE*

```
var objJson = { "toto" : val1, "toto2" : val2};

$("#ElementID").attr("attributName", JSON.strigify(objJson));
```

*READ*

```
var objJson = JSON.parse($("#ElementID").attr("attributeName"));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am clueless how to incorporate this unfortunately.

Comment: Can you try explaining the relevance of this answer in context to the question?

Comment: He demand how to store multiple data into a single HTML balise attribute. This is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery on the page right? after each change event you can create the total:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var amt = $('#result').text();
  var newAmt = Number(amt) + Number($(this).val());
  console.log(newAmt);
});
```

$(this).val() may need to be altered to be $(this).attr('name') (to match your HTML), also consider changing the above code so not like a generic $('select').

You can access any property of the select, this is just an example of the price.

```
$(this).val() and $(this).attr('name')
```

will be most helpful to you

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to fix the concept first. Start by rewrite the HTML. Hope this helps :

```
    <form id="shopping_cart" onsubmit="" action="" method="" target=""> 
        <select id="chooseproduct" onchange="getprice()">
            <option value="2.0" >FirstProduct</option>
            <option value="2.5" >SecondProduct</option>
            <option value="3.5" >ThirdProduct</option>
            <option value="4.0" >FourthProduct</option>
        </select>
        <select id="choosecolor" onchange="getprice()">
            <option value="3.2">FirstColor</option>
            ...
        </select>   
        <select id="choosesize" onchange="getprice()">
            <option value="8.0">FirstSize</option>
            ...
        </select>       
        <div>Result is:</div><div id="result"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getprice(){   
        product = $("#chooseproduct").val();
        color = $("#choosecolor").val();
        size = $("#choosesize").val();

        var calculate = product*color*size;
        var result = $("#result");
        result.html($("option:selected","#chooseproduct").text());
    }
</script></form>
```

Comment: Please don't just use code as your answer. Why is this better than what the OP already had?

Comment: IMHO, the HTML need to be changed because I think the real 'value' are the numbers that used to calculate the price. Therefore the numbers need to be stored in `value` attribute. The name (eq:"FirstProduct") need not to be saved in attributes, hence it already available (as label) in the `select` element.

Comment: More proper use of HTML semantic will ease us to write the JS code. CMIIW.

Comment: My answer was down voted. Please someone be kind to explain the reason ? :(

Comment: The reason was already given. Provide an explanation and I will up vote. Don't just dump HTML as an answer.

Comment: (i.e. Edit your answer with an explanation rather than adding it in to  the comments)

Comment: He stated in the question that the value attribute is used by an offsite script which cannot be modified.